# Testing for an XML attribute

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet

I have a piece of XML like so:

```
<root>
    <foo src=""/>
    <foo src="bar"/>
    <foo />
</root>
```

I want to know which **elements have a src attribute**, which are empty and which have values.

The furthest I have come is with

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//foo' -v @src -n foo.xml 

bar
```

Though that doesn't tell me the third foo is missing the attribute.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution (one-liner XPath expression) for each case. :)

Comment: @Dimitre: "complete": not quite...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This will select the foos with no `src` attribute.

```
/root/foo[not(@src)]
```

For the other two tasks, I would use a mix of the expressions pointed out by @TOUDIdel and @Dimitre Novatchev:
 `/root/foo[@src and string-length(@src)=0]` for foos with an empty `src`, and `/root/foo[@src and string-length(@src)!=0]` for foos with an `src` with content in it.

As an aside, I would avoid using the "anywhere" selector, `//` (not to mention the `*` wildcard), unless you're sure that this is specifically what you need. `//` is like making your very eager dog sniff a piece of cloth and telling it, "bring me everything that smells like this, wherever you find it". You won't believe the weird crap it can decide to bring back.

Comment: I love to dog & cloth analogy! =0

Comment: thanks for you're answer, where can I found that "string-length" functions and others?

Answer (score 16):

> I want to know which **elements have a src attribute**, which are empty and which have values.

Elements having a `@src` attribute which is empty (no string-value):

```
//*[@src[not(string())]]
```

Elements having a `@src` attribute which has value (string-value):

```
//*[string(@src)]
```

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean

> A string is true if and only if its length is non-zero.

Comment: would `//*[not(string())]` mean something without any attributes?

Comment: With the above, a `src="   "` attribute would be considered a non-empty attribute. Which is why [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580372/testing-for-an-xml-attribute#5582026) uses the [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function.

Answer (score 6):

`/root/foo[string-length(@src)!=0]` return all *foo* elements have non empty value.

Unfortunately `/root/foo[string-length(@src)=0]` indicates elements which don't have *src* attribute and also elements have *src* attribute but empty.

Comment: Well this doesn't solve the problem then! I need to importantly distinguish between when the attribute is missing and when the attribute is empty. :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Use**:

```
//*[@src and not(string-length(@src))]
```

This selects all elements in the XML document that have a `src` attribute whose string-value has length of zero.

```
//*[@src and string-length(@src)]
```

This selects all elements in the XML document that have a `src` attribute whose string-value has length that is not zero.

```
//*[@src and string-length(normalize-space(@src))]
```

This selects all elements in the XML document that have a `src` attribute whose string-value after excluding the starting and ending whitespace has length that is not zero.

```
//[not(@src)]
```

This selects all elements in the XML document that don't have a `src` attribute.

Comment: Still I don't see a method of testing that the src attribute is there at all. :/ I want to flag the `<foo />` case for missing the src attribute.

Comment: @Hendry: Why, all expressions do test exactly that: `someExpr[@src]` means: select all nodes that `someExpr` selects and that have a `src` attribute.

Comment: @Dimetre: to spell it out, he means testing that the `src` attribute is NOT there. Just use the `not` operator; see my answer.

Comment: @Jean-François-Corbett: Thanks, but this is not what the OP asked in his comment: "a method of testing that the src attribute is there at all"

Comment: @hendry: You wrote _"I want to know which **elements have a src attribute**"_.

Comment: @Dimitre: I think that second and third could be simplified to `//*[string-length(@src)]` and `//*[normalize-space(@src)]`. Also look up the missing parentheses typo.

Comment: @Alejandro:Good catch -- fixed. As for simplifications, the OP made it clear he wants to see if when the attribute *exists* it is "empty.