# How to search for empty/void nodes/elements in XPath?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have the following XML sample for which I need a XPath query to return **only** `node1` and `node3`.

```
<root>
    <node1 />
    <node2 anyAttribute="anyText" />
    <node3> </node3>
    <node4>anyText</node4>
    <node5>
        <anyChildNode />
    </node5>
</root>
```

In other words a XPath query which returns all nodes which have (simultaneously):

1. no attributes
2. no child nodes
3. no or whitespace-only content

I've found some solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744783/4469405) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582026/4469405)) but which are only applicable to one of the points above at a time:

- for 1. `/root/node()[not(node())]` - tested and works
- for 2. `/root/node()[not(@*)]` - tested and works
- for 3. `/root/node()[string-length(normalize-space(text())) = 0]` - not working (dunno why)

Yes, I know, I could use the 3 variants above together, but I would like to avoid it and I would think that for just searching for empty nodes/elements there should be an easy way, or?

---

I'm also limited to `xPath 1.0` on `.NET`, since [there is no progress](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2295) on supporting newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/root/*[not(@* or * or text()[normalize-space()])]
```

will select only `node1` and `node3`, as requested.

**Explanation:**
Select all *element* (note difference from *node*) children of `root` that have no children that are attributes (`@*`) or elements (`*`) or non-whitespace text (`text()[normalize-space()]`).

Comment: +1 works fine; was thinking that using `node()` would be faster than `*` but seems that I've confused it with `\\\`.